# Mongodb merge using dynamic field value as collection name

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am trying to do merge stage in MongoDB aggregation pipeline to a target collection.
The name for target collection in `$merge` stage needs to be passed using field value of document got from previous stage .

Below is my pipeline stage for merge that I am using . Here I need to pass a dynamic field ..**'$sender_id'** which is field value of document from prev stage … to **‘coll’** parameter of **$merge** but it is throwing this error :

PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Invalid collection name: `$sender_id`

```
  $merge: {
    into: {
      "db": "conversations_archive",
      "coll": "$sender_id"
    },
    on: "_id",
    // let: {sender_id: '$sender_id'},
    // whenMatched: 'keepExisting',
    // whenNotMatched: 'insert' }
  }
```

I tried using new operator as well as double dollar but none worked even `$toString` didn’t work .

Please help .

I tried using double operator , new operator `$$new.sender_id`  , as well as `$toString` operator.

Comment: As of v5.0.6, the `db` and `coll ` arguments may not be dynamic values from documents in the aggregation pipeline.